# preg match not taking large letter number combo

Tags: php, preg-match

Preg match will not accept example: Swbermanoo0292. I also would like to allow quotes but cannot figure how to do so. I have searched but cannot find the answer.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3}*$/", $newuser2) || 
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()!?:\s]*$/", $description)){
//action code here
}
```

I get error:  "PHP Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 13 in..."

I have got the username now with: `(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $newuser2))`

But when I try: `(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()!?:\"\s]*$/", $description))` the regex tester states

> / An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a `backslash (\)`

Comment: that first regex is not valid. your code should throw you some errors, have you configured php to display them? (specifically, both `{0,3}` and `*` are quantifiers, and you can't quantify a quantifier)

Comment: I just checked. Yes... "PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 13 in..." How can I acomplish the example given and add " to accepted symbols?

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve. playing around with https://regex101.com/ might help you solve your problem and get better at regexes

Comment: Hey Thanks! I will look at it.

Comment: What are the pattern requirements? What kind of strings do you want to match ("allow")?

Comment: "Swbermanoo0292" (with the quotes)

Comment: It is an example string. Why should it be matched? Did you try just adding `"` to the regex? `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()!?:\"\s]*$/", $description)`?

Comment: I did. I did not put in the slash right.

Comment: Can you please help with the username preg match also? example username: Swbermanoo0292

Comment: Your current code in the question is fine and does not cause any issues. Please update the code to show the *issue*.